# Margin between image and wrapping text doesn't appear properly in Window Outlook (Email HTML)

Tags: html, windows, outlook

I am working on a template for email newsletter, and one of the parts have an image wrapped around texts. The spacing between them works perfectly fine in other emails but it breaks when sent to Outlook Windows.

[How it looks in Outlook Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n10Jk.png)

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 0;margin-right:0;margin-bottom: 40px;margin-left: 0;text-align: left;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" align="center">
            <tr style="margin-top: 0;margin-right:0;margin-bottom: 32px;margin-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;"><td style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                <h2 style="font-size: 30px;font-weight: 500;text-align: center;line-height: 48px;margin-top: 40px;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 32px;margin-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;">Topic one here</h2>
            </td></tr>
            <tr style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;"><td style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                <img src="https://www.aesop.com/u1nb1km7t5q7/4uahoGkAUbKTdgi26UWS8U/d35893987804270676a1ab2a46ad2038/Our-Story-Carousel-1-Desktop-2880x1620.jpg" align="left" alt="Topic 1" style="width: 250px;margin-top: 0;margin-right:16px;margin-bottom: 8px;margin-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;"><p style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: medium;line-height: 27px;color: #333;margin-top: 0;margin-right:0;margin-bottom: 16px;margin-left: 0px;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tristique eros magna. Duis pretium finibus urna id vestibulum. Quisque sollicitudin eros ultricies, finibus lacus suscipit, viverra ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tristique eros magna. Duis pretium finibus urna id vestibulum. Quisque sollicitudin eros ultricies, finibus lacus suscipit, viverra ante.</p>
                <p style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: medium;line-height: 27px;color: #333;margin-top: 0;margin-right:0;margin-bottom: 16px;margin-left: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tristique eros magna. Duis pretium finibus urna id vestibulum. Quisque sollicitudin eros ultricies, finibus lacus suscipit, viverra ante.</p>
            </td></tr>
```

Comment: I haven't seen any mistake in the code. can you try using overflow:hidden; in the frist <td>

Comment: ^ This answer won't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're most likely not going to get this to work in Outlook. This type of layout isn't conducive to having the option to add spacing or padding as you wish, like you would get with a table cell or div.

You're probably better off setting the two elements up in two table cells, or even better - two aligned tables so they can stack on mobile. The only drawback to these two methods is that the text will no longer be able to wrap around the image as you have it currently.

Desktop Outlook programs for Windows haven't caught up with the latest capabilities for email and most likely won't for a long time!